# Python recursive zeno() function

Tags: python, recursion

In python, I need to define a recursive function that takes a number a returns the sum 1/2^0 + 1/2^1 + 1/2^2 + 1/2^3 + ... + 1/2^n. I need to accomplish this without using a for or while loop. This is what i have tried.

```
def zeno(n):
    if n==0:
        return 1/1
    else:
        return float(1/1 + 1/2**zeno(n-1))
```

Comment: That's nice - so what's the problem you're experiencing in doing so?

Comment: What would a function look like that returned the last `1/2^n` and then add that to a call to that function with `n-1` as an argument.  Also add some error checking to not do any more adding if `n==0`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: This is what i have tried. def zeno(n):

    if n==0:
        return 1/1
    else:
        return  float(1/1 + 1/2**zeno(n-1))

Comment: Ah, I think I see your bug, you aren't calculating the `1/2^n` case.

Comment: Two mistakes: a) you're adding 1 in every call, not just the n==0 base case b) You're adding `1/2**zeno(n-1)` instead of simply adding `zeno(n-1)` itself. So for the n==2 call you're adding `1/2**1.5`, instead of just adding 1.5 itself!

Comment: Other minor things: `1/1` is just 1. And to get a float division result, instead of `float(1/2**n)`, just do `1./2**n` . (or in Python 3 '/' automatically does float division anyway)

Answer (score 3):

```
def zeno(n):
    if n==0: 
        return 1 #return 1 for base n==0 case, x ^ 0 is always 1
    else:
        return 0.5**n + zeno(n-1)  #calculate (1/2) ^ n + (1/2)^(n-1) recursively
```